# How do I make this 'mutate' sentences using loop or other functions in R?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

Here is my code;

```
structure(list(VALUE = c(29.95, 1.48, 1, 39.28, 159.2, 68.3)), .Names = "VALUE", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dta_n4 <- dta_n3 %>%
  mutate(VALUE_3 = ifelse(VALUE < 3, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(VALUE_6 = ifelse(VALUE < 6, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(VALUE_9 = ifelse(VALUE < 9, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(VALUE_12 = ifelse(VALUE < 12, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(V_VALUE_3 = VALUE_3 * 100) %>%
  mutate(V_VALUE_6 = VALUE_6 * 100) %>%
  mutate(V_VALUE_9 = VALUE_9 * 100) %>%
  mutate(V_VALUE_12 = VALUE_12 * 100)
```

How do I make the 'VALUE_n' using loop (3, 6, 9, 12)?

Comment: Unclear what you're looking for here. Can you edit your question to include a full description of the problem you're trying to solve, your expected output, and any attempts you've made at getting that output? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance on asking clear questions

Comment: I attached more in the question thanks.

Comment: Ajhyeon, please provide sample data. The addition of `seq(3,9,3)` provides very little in the way of context. I suggest the output from `dput(head(dta_fin))`, as it provides an unambiguous representation of your data.

Comment: I make the sample data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using super fast `for-set` in one iteration, you can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df). ## df is your data

cols <- c(3,6,9,12)

for(i in cols){
    temp_col <- paste0('VALUE_', as.character(i))
    set(x = df, j = temp_col, value = ifelse(df$VALUE < i, 1, 0))    
    set(x = df, j = paste0('V_', temp_col), value=df[[temp_col]]*100)
}

    VALUE VALUE_3 V_VALUE_3 VALUE_6 V_VALUE_6 VALUE_9 V_VALUE_9 VALUE_12 V_VALUE_12
1:  29.95       0         0       0         0       0         0        0          0
2:   1.48       1       100       1       100       1       100        1        100
3:   1.00       1       100       1       100       1       100        1        100
4:  39.28       0         0       0         0       0         0        0          0
5: 159.20       0         0       0         0       0         0        0          0
6:  68.30       0         0       0         0       0         0        0          0
```